# Best Practices ON DELETE CASCADE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL(innoDB) database that is growing and it's necessary to define a cleaning strategy for old rows.

My first purpose was set FK with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option but I don't know if that suppose any performance issue...

Any suggestion? Which are the best practices for cleaning old data?

Comment: Not a fan of on Delete cascade because many times it is the FK which prevents deleting a record that should not be deleted. For instance, you should not delete a customer who has actual orders. Since on delete cascade tends to work against all tables with FK relationships, it doesn't give you the flexibility to choose to save the things you should be saving. I would never allow this to be set on any database I manage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First having too many rows in never a reason to delete rows.** It is a reason to get better hardware perhaps.

**So the cleaning strategy should be to delete rows that no longer serve a business purpose.** In determining those rows, it is often more likely you want to archive not delete, so that the data will be available if you need to do historical research. It should be extremely rare that you delete rows from a database.

So in creating a strategy, you could do several things. First define what is the business need to keep each type of data you are storing.  Perhaps you only need to see the last year's worth of data perhaps the last five, it depends on the business need. Perhaps you only want to see active customers or want to delete items that were in a wishlist over a year old.  Without understanding the business meaning of the data no one can help you devise a strategy for deleting.

On delete cascade is a particularly bad thing to use to clean data because it doesn't discriminate against the data you want the FK to stop the delete for and the data you are trying to completely purge. If you are deleting large amounts of records and have lots of FKS, it can also tie up your system from any processing for quite some time. Further, deleting without thought concerning the meaning of the data and why you keep it is a sure route to losing data you need.  There is no simple quick fix for determining what to keep and what to archive or delete. So don't use that as a first choice ever.

Likely what would serve you best is to create archive tables and move old data manually to them in batches. You can tell what data is related by the FKs on the parent table (assuming you correctly designed with FKs instead of letting the application handle all that (always a bad choice.).  Or you can do partitioning of data in many systems to keep the data but improve the query performance. Alternatively you can use views to access only the most recent data and that too can, if correctly designed, improve performance without deleting any data at all. Or you can move all data to a datawarehouse and design a process to remove all data over a certain time period.

If you choose to delete data, make sure to take a full backup of the database first and store it off-site.

You would be amazed at how often old data can come back to haunt you later. Currently I am working on task to get data back almost 20 years for a legal case a former customer is involved with. (I work in a highly regulated industry. But we never delete anything and all of our past data is available in our archive server. So this is not a problem for us.) If there is any chance that you are working in a regulated industry (such as finance or health care or police work or the Defense industry) or that there may be legal action in the future, do not delete data, store it in an archive. This is one reason why it is critical to understand the business needs before considering deleting any data at all.

Comment: After quick analizing bussiness purpose of our application's data it seems that the best option will be ARCHIVE rather tan DELETE.
I  consider my case as a time series one, where for instance it's a good practice to apply partitioning by month/year and for the real old and unnecessary data we can do a nearly DROP PARTITION plus REORGANIZE PARTITION instead of much slower DELETE.

Answer (score 5):

The `ON DELETE` option of mySql when adding a new foreign key can be set to 3 differents behaviors :

1. `RESTRICT` (also called `NO ACTION`) is the default behavior in mysql, and will stop the process and throw an error.
2. `SET NULL` will set the foreign key value to `null` whenever it is deleted. (This will keep entries in DB)
3. `CASCADE` will totally delete the foreign key from the DB and also every entries that are related to it.

**Warning :** Only use the `CASCADE` behavior whenever you sure that your datas need to be deleted if they aren't related to anything. (*Ex: Comments for a blog's post...*)

Technically, and I'm not an expert in database performance optimization, but the `SET NULL` option seems to maximise the performance while the `CASCADE`'s one maximise storage.